# how to check result of doctrine statement

Tags: codeigniter, orm, doctrine-orm

I use this code to remove data from database using doctrine

```
$user = $em->getReference('model\User', $id);
$em->remove($user);
$em->flush();
```

how I can check if the $user is deleted or not?

what is the returned data from `$em->flush();`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have used `try` and `catch()` blocks to solve this issue 
when try excute correctly i have return true and in catch i return False