# Doctrine how to check if flush() is successful?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Using Doctrine I am trying to check if `flush()` is successful.

before my ORM days I used to do `if ( $query->execute() ) {}`

Since `flush()` returns void, I am not convinced that using `try catch` would solve the problem like [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40201851/how-to-check-result-of-doctrine-statement) ? Would it ?

If not, is there a way to achieve something similar ?

Comment: The accepted answer is correct but it then raises the question of what to do with the caught exception.  Similar to the quandary a dog faces when it actually catches the truck it is chasing.  You typically have very limited recovery options.  The entity manager is no longer usable (though you can generate a new one).  You are buried somewhere deep in your code and it can be difficult to dig out.  In most cases you can just let the framework's global exception handler take care of these issues.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Under the hood, PDO will throw an exception if executing the query fails. Doctrine will not silence this exception (it will wrap it, but rethrow). So just making sure no exception is thrown is enough to check if everything was executed successfully.

Comment: even with mysql engine ?

Comment: Yes, that's a feature of PDO (see http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php) that is enabled for you under the hood by Doctrine DBAL.

Comment: As long as you use PDO it doesn't matter which engine you use.

Answer (score -2):

if you want to know if an entity has been flushed, you can make use doctrine event listener (https://symfony.com/doc/3.0/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html)

the help you to make an action automatically after a persist event

Comment: While the page you linked gives the answer today, you should include the code that supplies an answer in your answer. That link may one day die while your answer lives, creating a nonsensical situation.